# Excel crash while trying to insert VSTO addin formula from Office JS Taskpane

Tags: excel-formula, vsto, office-js, excel-dna, office-js-helpers

I am facing an odd issue while connecting VSTO addin formula with office js taskpane. Below is the scenario

1. There is one VSTO addin which has several formulas defined in it.
2. One newly created office js taskpnae has included as new product and we are trying to use existing formula from the VSTO addin.

But while inserting any formula from office js to sheet excel is getting crashed. we are returning values from the formula as below

return ExcelAsyncUtil.Observe(
"ABC",
new object[] { parameters },
() => Methoddetails).ToExcelObservable());

We can see the log as below also
2020-10-10 07:26:36.5178 [ERROR] [T:1] - The RTD server of type ExcelDna.Integration.Rtd.ExcelObserverRtdServer required by add-in addinname could not be registered.
This is an unexpected error.
Error message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Can someone help me on this, what could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: Does the formula work correctly when you enter it manually?

Comment: sorry for late reply, we actually fixed it by mentioning IsMacroType as False.

Comment: Do you mean the problem is present if the function is marked as `IsMacroType=true` and the problem goes away if you have `IsMacroType=false`?

Comment: Yes .. If I set it as IsMacroType = False , excel is working as expected. It is getting crashed whenever we set it as True,

Comment: Excel-DNA is a different library to VSTO - it would help to clarify what you are using.

Comment: Does Excel crash, or do you just get an error from Excel-DNA that pops up?

Comment: I've filed an issue on the Excel-DNA Github repository https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/355 , but I'm not sure when it will get investigated further - I don't really work with the Javascript stuff.

Comment: Excel crashed actually , i tried to find out any windows log but it did not work. Only solution was the above one.